# How to trick a BMS into thinking the battery is connected?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, bms

I purchased a Wireless Audio Adapter off of Amazon for a DIY sound system. The sound system runs off a wall switch, but because there is a battery inside the device it stays powered on after switching it 'off' at the wall. It has a VERY aggressive Bluetooth connection strategy, so when the power is turned off, I want the device to power off, not remain powered on due to the battery inside.

Removing the battery achieves my goal of true off/on, but it has resulted in the device making a small hissing / buzzing noise. This noise is a physical noise, not a digital audio noise. I expect this is due to the built-in TP4056 trying to charge the battery and there not being anything to charge. The hissing sound goes away again after re-connecting the battery. Hissing in electronics is not good, so I'd like to solve the underlying issue.

My gut instinct is to just slap a capacitor or resistor over the GND-VBAT+ rails but I am not willing to try without knowing for sure. The price of the audio adaptor has limited my willingness to try without a second opinion. My questions are:

- Are the desired modifications safe at all?
- Is operating it without any modifications besides removing the battery safe?
- What component would one use to trick the BMS/charger into behaving like there is a battery present (and stopping the noise)?
- What rating/size component would be safe to use in place of a battery (and how is that calculated)?

*Safe* to me means the device will continue to operate, and not burn my house down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Burn baby burn ,The tanty caps are a red flag .The PCB is Klap Lubbish

Comment: What's wrong with Tantalum capacitors ( I assume this is what you mean )? And what does Klap Lubbish mean?

Comment: This question isn't really on topic without more information, there isn't a way to answer questions about the device without a schematic or additional information

Comment: Is tricking a BMS to thinking there is a battery there not within the realm of Electrical Engineering? If not, is there another forum you suggest? If the question is truly not appropriate I'll remove.

Comment: I'd try desoldering and lifting pin 8 (Chip Enable) of the TP4056 IC (north of the battery terminals in your image) and wiring it to a ground pad. That should fully disable the charging behaviour.

Comment: Buy another adaptor of different design.

Comment: @Frostytheswimmer `Klap Lubbish` it may have be a regional expression ... maybe someone that makes no distinction between the sound of the letter  `L` and the sound of the letter `R` said it a lot, and it became an expression  in that neighborhood ... there are some languages that do not use one or both of those sounds, and it is difficult for a native speaker to distinguish the two ... interesting thing is that it is also like that with distinguishing color

Comment: Also, there's nothing wrong with the tantalum caps. They're completely unrelated to your problem and the reputation they have for "burning" is based off older tantalum capacitors' tendency to catch fire when they fail, due to oxygen release via thermal decomposition at internal microfissure boundaries when an excessive voltage is applied across the capacitor. Modern tantalum capacitor constructions take measures to prevent this and many use an alternative material that absorbs oxygen instead of releasing it.

Comment: @Polynomial, disconnecting Pin 8 was the solution to my problem, but not the answer to the question! Exactly what I was looking for, my original question was me over thinking it!